# jQuery Accordion navigationFilter open header with current page

Tags: jquery, variables, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

just a quick one here but only for jQuery experts.

What would be the best way to have the jQuery accordion always open the header which holds the link to page the user currently is on?

Current code:

```
  $(function () {
        $('ul.drawers').accordion({
            header: 'H2.drawer-handle',
            selectedClass: 'open',
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            event: 'mouseover',
            navigation: true,
        });
});

$('ul.drawers').accordion('option', 'navigationFilter', function(){   
        //Your code for the NavigationFilter }); 
</script>
```

All the best,
Robert

here is the html:

```
<ul class="drawers"> 
<li class="drawer"> 
<h2 class="drawer-handle"><a class="lahtine" href="http://www.viking.ee/en/outwardwindows/">Outward Opening Windows</a></h2> 
<div class="menu-outward-opening-windows-container"><ul id="menu-outward-opening-windows" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-789" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-789"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/aluclad/">Aluminium Clad Wooden Windows</a></li> 
<li id="menu-item-790" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-790"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/doubleglazedwindow/">Double Glazed Window</a></li> 
<li id="menu-item-791" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-791"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/tripleglazing/">Energy Efficient Triple Glazed Window</a></li> 
<li id="menu-item-792" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-792"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/secure/">Secured By Design</a></li> 
</ul></div></li> 
<li class="drawer"> 
<h2 class="drawer-handle"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/inwardwindows/">Inward Opening Windows</a></h2> 
<div class="menu-inward-opening-windows-container"><ul id="menu-inward-opening-windows" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-793"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/woodenwindows/">Inward Opening Wooden Windows</a></li> 
<li id="menu-item-794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-794"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/timberthermalwindow/">Timber Thermal Window</a></li> 
</ul></div></li> 
<li class="drawer"> 
<h2 class="drawer-handle"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/selection/">Additional Selection</a></h2> 
<div class="menu-additional-selection-container"><ul id="menu-additional-selection" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-795" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-795"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/fireguard/">Viking Fireguard Window</a></li> 
<li id="menu-item-796" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-796"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/slidingsash/">Traditional Sliding Sash</a></li> 
</ul></div></li> 
<li class="drawer"> 
<h2 class="drawer-handle"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/exteriordoors/">Exterior Doors</a></h2> 
<div class="menu-exterior-doors-2-container"><ul id="menu-exterior-doors-2" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-797" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type current-menu-item menu-item-797"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/doors/alucladdoors/">Viking Double Glazed Alu-Clad Door</a></li> 
<li id="menu-item-798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-798"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/doors/tripleglazed/">Energy Efficient Triple Glazed Wooden Doors</a></li> 
</ul></div></li> 
<li class="drawer last"> 
<h2 class="drawer-handle"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/slidingdoors/">Sliding/Folding Doors</a></h2> 
<div class="menu-sliding-and-folding-doors-container"><ul id="menu-sliding-and-folding-doors" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-799" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-799"><a href="http://www.viking.ee/en/doors/sliding/">The Sliding Door</a></li> 
</ul></div></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code/html, or knowing which accordion pluggin you are specifically using.

I would say the simplest way would be to compare the document.location.pathname (or parse from it just the filename.html) and then you can do a couple of things.

1) run a function using the above to add the required class to the item that matches your current location (url) so when the menu is initialized it knows which to expand

2) run a function after the menu is initialized, to detect which which header contains your current page and trigger the event to expand it.  Are you using the jQuery UI accordion?  if so the syntax is:

```
       `$(yourMenuSelector).accordion("activate",indexOfHeaderToOpen);`
```

Glad to help if you can provide more info, but this should get the wheels spinning.

Comment: I am using the the old one with jQuery 1.3.2. - by old I mean the version that is not part of jQuery UI currently - but yes it is the same plugin that was combined into jQuery UI and most of the stuff works with it

Comment: did you get it sorted?  according to how you init the menu, you have "selectedClass: 'open' " stated, so simply add that class to the header you want to be expanded prior to initializing it.